# How to save an incoming filestream from Node into AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pdf, filesaver.js

On my express server I have a post-request which is getting a pdf file from Amazon S3 and sending it back to angular. This is how my express server endpoint ends with:

```
var fileStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
fileStream.pipe(res);
```

On the angular side of things I am posting and trying to save this

```
$http.post(url, data)
.then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  var file = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  FileSaver.saveAs(file, vm.projectName);
})
```

I get a pdf file which is not valid. I has about 300kb (more than original file) and I believe its not pdf but a buffer?

What I am trying to achieve:
- Post Request to server
- Server gets file from S3, Sends it back to Angular Controller
- Angular Controller saves it as .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're making POST call, set `responseType` of request to `arrayBuffer` inside configuration, so that response will get transformed to correctly.

```
$http.post(url, data, {responseType: "arraybuffer"})
```

Comment: Thank your sir! Exactly what I needed